# loading t:dataTable in JSF asynchronously using jQuery

Tags: jsf, jquery

```
<t:panelTab label="Detailed View" styleClass="tabFont" rendered="true" id="DetailedView">
    <t:dataTable value="#{MyFinanceBB.amendDataList}" id="DetailedViewGrid" forceId="true"
                var="myVo" rowIndexVar="gridExpRowNo"......>
    ...............
      <t:inputText value="#{myVo.myval}" styleClass="BodyFont" forceId="true" id="myId2"
                                    onchange="getTotalMyValAjax('myId2[#{gridExpRowNo}]',#{gridExpRowNo});">
```

/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
function getMyAmountTotalGrid(myidVar,count){   

            var myAmt=document.getElementById(myidVar).value;

            var id = 'myForm\\:targetView';

                $j.ajax({
                    async:"false",
                    cache:"false",
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"/myProj/myController",
                    data:{myAmt:myAmt,count:count},
                    error:function(){
                        alert('Error Occurred.Please try later');
                        },  
                    success:function(output){
                                alert('SUCCESS');
                                 $j('#'+id).load("/pagesmyProj/Home/dingDongHome.jsf");
                                alert('after reloading grid');                                          
                        }
                    }); 
        }
```

---

when i execute the code alert message SUCCESS is getting printed and all the server side variables are getting updated.(I came to know this by sysouts). But nothing is really getting changed in the webpage. The alert message "after relaoding grid" is also getting printed. But the grid is not getting reloaded. The server side changes are not getting reflected in the browser.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If the first alert fires, but the second one doesn't, the line in between is likely erroring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For start you should add `\\` to your id

instead of `var id = 'myForm:targetView';`

write `var id = 'myForm\\:targetView';` otherwise jquery selector by id wont work (you need to escape the `:`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the alert 'after reloading grid' is coming. But webpage is not getting changed.(The server side changes are not really getting reflected in the browser).

Comment: This functionality is working fine.(continuation of the above question) But there is some <t:inputCalendar value="#{MyFinanceBB.departDate}" ....>. This calender tag is working perfectly fine. But when i change some thing and Ajax functionality is called, then this t:inputCalendar tag does not show necessary pop-up to edit the date in that field.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing

```
$j('#'+id)...
```

just remove the "j", ex. $('#'+id)...

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle,I got the error.The url given to the jquery load function is not proper and it should be changed.